# How to unzip an Array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

How to unzip an Array in Ruby like this examples in Python:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = [4, 5, 6]
>>> zipped = zip(x, y)
>>> zipped
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
>>> x2, y2 = zip(*zipped)
>>> x == list(x2) and y == list(y2)
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use [`transpose`](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Array/transpose):

```
> zipped = x.zip(y)
=> [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
> x2, y2 = zipped.transpose
> x2
=> [1, 2, 3]
> y2
=> [4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: If `x.size > y.size`, `transpose` is not quite the inverse of `zip` as it will add `nil`s to the end of `y2`.  If neither original contains nil using `zipped.transpose.map(&:compact)` restores the originals.